# Is there a SQLCMD equivalent on *nix?

Tags: unix, sqlcmd

We have a heterogeneous environment where some developers are using OSX and some are using Windows.  Our build process involves DB revision control and needs to call SQLCMD to execute arbitrary scripts - our databases are all SQL Server.

SQLCMD is the command line interface to SQL Server on Windows, similar to Oracle's SQL*Plus.  The particular functionality we need is the ability to run SQL scripts from the command line.  Is there a SQLCMD equivalent for *nix?

If there isn't then the only cross-platform approach I can think of would be to load a script file into memory, then execute the script.

Is there a clear leader for a library/language combination that will handle all T-SQL DDL statements?  (I ask about DDL statements because they have been the hangup on this approach when I've tried it in the past.)

Comment: General point: when asking for the Platform equivalent of Foo, it is useful to say what Foo is/does for the benefit of those who work on Platform but don't know anything about Foo. Providing a link wouldn't hurt, and saying *exactly* what features of Foo you need would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the `fisql` utility, which is part of [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/), an open-source implementation of the SQL Server wire protocol.  `fisql` is purported to be a clone of the ancient `isql`, predecessor of `osql`, predecessor of `sqlcmd`, but presumably it will work with any level of T-SQL.

*Disclaimer: I haven't used FreeTDS myself.*